# How can I change Layout in Controller's Method (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I used multiple layouts in Laravel using code as below, it works.

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    ...
}
```

But now I want to change the layout in Method (In UsersController)

```
public function myFunc(){

    //I want to change myFunc's layout to 'default2'

    $this->layout->content = View::make('user.myfunc');
}
```

How can I do? Because when I use `$this->layout = 'layouts.default2'`

it always returns me `ErrorException: Attempt to assign property of non-object`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this in your controller method :

```
public function myFunc(){
    $this->layout = View::make('layouts.default2');
    $this->layout->content = View::make('user.myfunc');
}
```